React CSS multiple inline styles VS class performance-wise
Who wins from performance perspective (only)
INLINE STYLES
<div style={{backgroundColor:"#fff"}}>content</div>
<div style={{backgroundColor:"#fff"}}>content</div>
<div style={{backgroundColor:"#fff"}}>content</div>

CLASSNAME
div {
background-color:"#fff";
}


Recently i've been using inline styles as much as i can, when i build my project i see CSS files are so light cause not much content, i think inline styles are more performant, am i wrong ?

Which particular aspect of performance are you interested in? (e.g. load times, run times, time to insert elements via JS .....). Having asked that, I doubt I'll be much use because the way these things are implemented has got to be so dependent on an individual browser's implementation. I'd be far more concerned about what makes the code most easily maintained/understodd by others in future.
